# Creating a splash page with WPML language selector appearing only once and redirecting to website root URL

Tags: splash-screen, wpml

I need a splash page with WPML language selector. When users visiting the site for the first time select a language, they should be redirected to my site's root URL (www.my_site.com) with the right language selected.

Is there any simple way to achieve this, like a plugin? I found a couple threads on Internet about it but none fully resolved.